# wso2esb - REST API Failure doing XML to XML mapping

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

[image: Failure scenarios listed in red]

I am not able to make a call to REST backend from a browser[Rest client] using WSO2 ESB when trying the scenarios listed in Red.

**Content Type and MessageFormatter already tried**, am i doing something wrong or this is a limitation of REST API.

**Source Code for Scenario A :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InvokeASservice" context="/invokeWS" hostname="10.203.101.76">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="sequence" value="** Request Recieved**"/>
            </log>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/get?id=',get-property('uri.var.str1'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://10.203.101.76:9765/services/PersonInfoService.PersonInfoServiceHttpEndpoint/"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full" separator=",">
                <property name="sequence" value="** Message recieved**"/>
            </log>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Browser Error:

[image: error message on browser]

**#####################Update#####################**

Scenario A seems to work after changing the source

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InvokeASservice" context="/invokeWS" hostname="10.203.101.76">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{str1}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="sequence" value="** Request Recieved**"/>
         </log>
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/get?id=',get-property('uri.var.str1'))" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://10.203.101.76:9765/services/PersonInfoService.PersonInfoServiceHttpEndpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

But, **Scenario C is still a unsolved puzzle** with the response coming in xml format.
tried adding the following to outSequence. Does not help

```
<outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
```

Comment: Do you see the first log" Request Recieved**""in esb console?

Comment: Then at that time do sou see the malformed xml tags? if you keep log level =full then you can see what is the message passing through the system

Comment: Adding this should work. <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/> What is the response you aregetting in the scenario c?

Comment: You have to enable the message builders and formatters fro JSON

Comment: Created a jira. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1958, you can add your comments there

Comment: Which version of WSO2 ESB is used?